# How can I find which VIM plugin is guilty for overloading my CPU

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I just done a fresh installation of Vim, and with this occasion I added some new plugins to my VIM configuration. The problem is that now, when I do the first change in the file, VIM blocks and one of my CPUs reach 100% load. This is also happening every now and then while I'm editing the file. This never happened in the previous configuration.
How can I find what plugin is killing my CPU?

Comment: By removing every plugins and adding them back one by one.

Comment: This is the method I'm trying to avoid, but if there is no other way...

Comment: Well, you could probably use a profiler. You could also think a few seconds about your plugins: some are completely passive until you invoke them and are probably unrelated to your issue, others may launch background processes at each keypress… The statusbar, for example, may update itself very often to display VCS status or whatever.

Comment: We don't know anything about your previous/current configuration. What plugins did you have? What plugins do you have? Your old `~/.vimrc`? Your new one? Your OS? Your Vim version?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As an alternative to [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl)'s (nice and simple) [trial-and-error approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137304/how-can-i-find-which-vim-plugin-guilty-for-overloading-my-cpu/10142026#comment12996746_10137304):

I've done such once using vim's built-in profiler: [`:he profile`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#profiling).

You might need to compile vim by yourself to activate (profiling is not enabled in the default vim distribution).

Then

```
:profile start filename
```

to activate profiling and write your profile data to `filename`, edit your file (which pushes the CPU to 100%), once done

```
:profdel
```

to stop profiling. Quit vim and you'll find the profiling information written in `filename`.

Comment: In debian squeeze, vim has profiling is enabled by default. Thanks eckes!

Comment: To profile everything, run
`:profile start filename`, then `:profile func *`
Then do the slow thing, and close vim.

`:profdel` is not needed - it doesn't stop profiling, it instead unmarks part of code for inclusion in profiling.

Comment: in neovim's case, there is https://github.com/stevearc/profile.nvim